# When button is clicked "Undefined" data is being written to the DB (Angular, Jade, Heroku, Node and PostgreSQL are being used)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, heroku, pug

My program is trying to add data to a PostgreSQL db on Heroku, but when I click the appropriate button it writes the data as "Undefined".  Am I making a mistake in the way I call the variables?

The app is using Node.js.  My approach for writing to the db was copied from from http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/webtech/how-to-use-postgresql-in-nodejs/, but I'm using Jade instead of html.

Here's the Jade page that shows the data and has a button to add to the db.  The $scope.addRecord function is defined here:

```
extends layout

block content
  div(id="container", ng-controller="postgreSQLCtrl")
    h2 Your Business Card's Data
    h3 You can edit any of the fields below. Just click on the field and type whatever you like. To add to the database click the button at the bottom.

    p.lead  Name:
       input(value=name, id="name", maxlength="30", width="600", ng-model="name", type="text")
    p.lead Description: 
      input(value=description, id="description", maxlength="30", width="600", ng-model="description", type="text")
    p.lead Location: 
      input(value=location, id="location", maxlength="30", width="600", ng-model="location", type="text")
    p.lead Company: 
      input(value=company, id="company", maxlength="30", width="600", ng-model="company", type="text")
    p.lead Title: 
      input(value=jtitle, id="jtitle", maxlength="30", width="600", ng-model="jtitle", type="text")
    p.lead URL for Your Photo: 
      input(value=photo, id="photo", maxlength="200", width="600", ng-model="photo", type="text")
    img(src= photo)
    | <button ng-click="addRecord()" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-danger">Add to db</button>

  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js')  
  script.
    var myApp = angular.module('postgreSQL',[ ]);
      myApp.controller('postgreSQLCtrl', ['$scope' ,'$http',  function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.addRecord = function(){
      var url = '/db/addRecord?name='+$scope.name+'&description='+$scope.description+'&location='+$scope.location+'&company='+$scope.company+'&jtitle='+$scope.jtitle+'&photo='+$scope.photo;
      console.log(url);
      $http({method: 'GET', url: '/db/addRecord?name='+$scope.name+'&description='+
      $scope.description+'&location='+$scope.location+'&company='+
      $scope.company+'&jtitle='+$scope.jtitle+'&photo='+$scope.photo}).
      success(function(data, status) {
      alert('Record Added');
      });
      }
      }]);
```

Here is the app's main js file.  A lot of this code deals with passport and might not be relevant.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Express middleware
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var logger = require('morgan');

// Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;  // source of strategy: https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2
var config = require('./config.json');
var pg = require('pg');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var dbOperations = require("./dbOperations.js");
var logFmt = require("logfmt");

// View engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


// Middleware
app.use(express.static('public')); // Put your static files here
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'shhhsupersecret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Logger
app.use(logger('dev'));


// heroku tells us to use this 
/*
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');

  client
    .query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;')
    .on('row', function(row) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    });
});
*/

// Passport session setup.
// to support persistent login sessions, passport needs to be able to
// serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
// this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
// the user by ID when deserializing.  However, since this example does not
// have a database of user records, the complete LinkedIn profile is
// serialized and deserialized.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
  clientID: config.LINKED_IN_CLIENT_ID,  
  clientSecret: config.LINKED_IN_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://shrouded-reef-9087.herokuapp.com/auth/linkedin/callback",
  scope: [ 'r_basicprofile' ],
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  // asynchronous verification, for effect... 
  req.session.accessToken = accessToken;
  process.nextTick(function () {
    // To keep the example simple, the user's LinkedIn profile is returned to 
    // represent the logged-in user. In a typical application, you would want 
    // to associate the LinkedIn account with a user record in your database, 
    // and return that user instead. 
    done(null, profile);
  });
}));

// Routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'LinkedIn Test Authorization'});
});

/*
from http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/webtech/how-to-use-postgresql-in-nodejs/

app.get('/' , function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile('views/index.html');
} );
*/
app.get('/db/readRecords', function(req,res){
    dbOperations.getRecords(req,res);
});
app.get('/db/addRecord', function(req,res){
    dbOperations.addRecord(req,res);
});
app.get('/db/delRecord', function(req,res){
    dbOperations.delRecord(req,res);
});
app.get('/db/createTable', function(req,res){
    dbOperations.createTable(req,res);
});
app.get('/db/dropTable', function(req,res){
    dbOperations.dropTable(req,res);
}); 

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  console.log('User Object: ', req.user);
  var name = req.user.displayName;
  var description = req.user._json.headline;
  var location = req.user._json.location.name;
  var company = req.user._json.positions.values[0].company.name;
  var jtitle = req.user._json.positions.values[0].title;
  var photo = req.user.photos[0];
  console.log('-----Desired data:  ',name,description,location,company,jtitle,photo);
  console.log('-----Desired data length:  ',name.length,description.length,location.length,company.length,jtitle.length,photo.length);
  res.render('user', {name: name, description: description, location: location, company: company, jtitle: jtitle, photo: photo, title: 'Your Business Card'});
});

// This sends the user to authenticate with linked-in
app.get('/auth/linkedin',
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', { state: 'asdfqwertlkjhz91xcv' }),
  function(req, res){
  // The request will be redirected to LinkedIn for authentication, so this 
  // function will not be called. 
});

// This is where we handle the callback and redirect the user
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function (req,res) {

    res.redirect('/user');
});

// The server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('LinkedIn Test app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

This is the dbOperations.js file, which defines the "addRecord" function that I'm trying to call with the angular $scope.addRecord function.

```
module.exports = {
  getRecords: function(req, res) {    
        var pg = require('pg');        
        //You can run command "heroku config" to see what is Database URL from Heroku belt
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres://postgres:Welcome123@localhost:5432/postgres";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();
        var query = client.query("select * from cards");
        query.on("row", function (row, result) { 
            result.addRow(row); 
        });
        query.on("end", function (result) {          
            client.end();
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "    ") + "\n");
            res.end();  
        });
  },
    addRecord : function(req, res){
        var pg = require('pg');          
        console.log("--------------req=",req);
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||  "postgres://postgres:Welcome123@localhost:5432/postgres";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();
        var query = client.query("insert into cards (name,description,location,company,jtitle,photo) "+ 
                                "values ('"+req.name+"','"+req.description+"','"+
                                    req.location+"','"+req.company+
                                    "','"+req.jtitle+"','"+req.photo+
                                    "')");    
        query.on("end", function (result) {          
            client.end(); 
            res.write('Success');
            res.end();  
        });
    },    
     delRecord : function(req, res){
        var pg = require('pg');           
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||  "postgres://postgres:Welcome123@localhost:5432/postgres";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();         
        var query = client.query( "Delete from cards Where id ="+req.query.id);    
        query.on("end", function (result) {          
            client.end(); 
            res.write('Success');
            res.end();  
        });
    },    
    createTable : function(req, res){
        var pg = require('pg');
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||  "postgres://postgres:Welcome123@localhost:5432/postgres";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();         
        var query = client.query( "CREATE TABLE cards"+
                                    "("+
                                      "name character varying(50),"+
                                      "description character varying(50),"+
                                      "location character varying(50),"+
                                      "company character varying(50),"+
                                      "jtitle character varying(50),"+
                                      "photo character varying(200),"+
                                      "id serial NOT NULL"+
                                    ")");    
        query.on("end", function (result) {          
            client.end(); 
            res.write('Table Schema Created');
            res.end();  
        });
    },    
    dropTable : function(req, res){
        var pg = require('pg');           
        var conString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || "postgres://postgres:Welcome123@localhost:5432/postgres";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect();         
        var query = client.query( "Drop TABLE cards");    
        query.on("end", function (result) {          
            client.end(); 
            res.write('Table Schema Deleted');
            res.end();  
        });
    }    
};
```

(This is an edited version of the original.  At first the function wasn't working due to  a misplaced ' symbol.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addRecord change it to `req.query.name` etc. instead of `req.name`.

Comment: Thanks, it's able to write data now.  Unfortunately this had the side effect of making all the input fields blank.. Previously they pre-populated with information retrieved from LinkedIn.  

e.g. <input value=name> caused it to pre-populate with the name variable.  Still, this is great progress.